# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. How do I prevent this error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is my code. I want to add a new expense item at the top of the list. I was hoping to get some help on how I can create a new expense at the top of the list. I keep getting the same error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. How can I fix this?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, View, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import NewExpense from "../NewExpense";
import {
  selectTitle,
  selectPrice,
  selectCategory,
} from "../../slices/dataSlice";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const RenderedExpense = () => {

  const title = useSelector(selectTitle);
  const price = useSelector(selectPrice);
  const category = useSelector(selectCategory);

  const enteredData = {
    id: Math.random().toString(),
    title: title.disTitle,
    price: price.disPrice,
    category: category.disCategory,
  };

  const expense = enteredData;

    const [expenseItems, setExpenseItems] = useState([]);
    setExpenseItems([expense, ...expenseItems]);


  return (
    <View>
      {
        (title.disTitle,
        price.disPrice,
        category.disCategory ? <NewExpense /> : null)
      }
      {
        expenseItems.map(() => {
          <NewExpense key={enteredData.id} /> })
      }
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: I think your infinite loop originates from here:
const [expenseItems, setExpenseItems] = useState([]);
setExpenseItems([expense, ...expenseItems]);

Answer (score 6):

Executing a `setState` triggers a re-render, so we should **never** have a `setState` inside the render method, or else an infitine loop happens.

Because you have the `setExpenseItems([expense, ...expenseItems]);` inside the render method, you will always get that exception.

You can put this part inside a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) that runs only when the values inside the brackets change, instead of every time the component renders:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const enteredData = {
            id: Math.random().toString(),
            title: title.disTitle,
            price: price.disPrice,
            category: category.disCategory,
        };

        const expense = enteredData;

        setExpenseItems([expense, ...expenseItems]);
    }, [title, price, category]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling your `setExpenseItems` within your directly inside your component, this will cause your component to re-render infinitely because whenever state is set, the component is re-rendered. So, it'll just keep setting the state and re-redering.

If you want to set the state as soon as the component loads you should use the `useEffect` hook.

Like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

...

const title = useSelector(selectTitle);
const price = useSelector(selectPrice);
const category = useSelector(selectCategory);

const enteredData = {
    id: Math.random().toString(),
    title: title.disTitle,
    price: price.disPrice,
    category: category.disCategory,
  };

const expense = enteredData;

const [expenseItems, setExpenseItems] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
    setExpenseItems([expense, ...expenseItems]);
},[])
...
```

Notice how I called `setExpenseItems` within `useEffect`. It'll call `setExpenseItems` only when the component is first rendered. useEffect also accepts a list of dependencies, which will determine if what ever is specified within the function will run. But I passed an empty array as my dependency.

See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), for more information.